# Navigation bar disappears when using custom Segue animation

Tags: ios, swift, segue

i'm trying to use custom segue animations in my app, however whenever i perform the segue the navigation bar disappears in the following VC. The animation and segue does work though

```
//calling prepare function and using .growscale animation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue is CustomSegue {
        (segue as! CustomSegue).animationType = .growScale
    }
}



//button performs Segue
@IBAction func exerciseLibrary(_ sender: UIButton) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "customSegue", sender: self)


}
```

I set the segue to custom as well, and i hope this is of any help but the VC that i am segueing to is a Collection View Controller

Update: Storyboard  [storyboard-main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x649C.png)

Comment: it would be helpful if you can post a screenshot of how you setup your `storyboard`

Comment: @f_qi hello, i've attached it above, i think it may be a little small since i tried to get all the VC's in one pic. let me know if i should reupload. thank u!

Comment: If you want to do custom animations with navigation controller, set a [`delegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621876-delegate) for your `UINavigationController`, implement [`navigation​Controller(_:​animation​Controller​For:​from:​to:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621876-delegate) to and return an animation controller. See WWDC 2013 video [Custom Transitions Using View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=218).

Comment: @Rob works! THANK YOU!